# Postfix is installed but how do I test it?

Tags: ubuntu, postfix-mta

I tried everything, I read online to test, and I can't get email to go out:

```
telnet <IP> 25
EHLO
MAIL FROM: <from-email>
RCPT TO: <recipient-email>
DATA
Type message here.
. <Enter>
=>
```

I even tried this, and when I type the period, I get nothing - but postfix is installed.

Comment: this post shows how to quickly setup postfix with gmail smtp port 587 and test it, and how to set your own email to receive all mail to root:  https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/731560/346155

Answer (score 54):

To check whether postfix is running or not

```
sudo postfix status
```

If it is not running, start it.

```
sudo postfix start
```

Then telnet to localhost port 25 to test the email id

```
ehlo localhost
mail from: root@localhost
rcpt to: your_email_id
data
Subject: My first mail on Postfix

Hi,
Are you there?
regards,
Admin
.
```

---

Do not forget the . at the end, which indicates end of line

Comment: @PJBrunet Yes, You can still check the status of the postfix using the status command as given in answer

Answer (score 18):

(I just got this working, with my main issue being that I don't have a real internet hostname, so answering this question in case it helps someone)

You need to specify a hostname with HELO. Even so, you should get an error, so Postfix is probably not running.

Also, the => is not a command. The '.' on a single line without any text around it is what tells Postfix that the entry is complete. Here are the entries I used:

```
telnet localhost 25
(says connected)
EHLO howdy.com
(returns a bunch of 250 codes)
MAIL FROM: somebody@blah.com
RCPT TO: (use a real email address you want to send to)
DATA (type whatever you want on muliple lines)
. (this on a single line tells Postfix that the DATA is complete)
```

You should get a response like:

250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 6E414C4643A

The email will probably end up in a junk folder. If it is not showing up, then you probably need to setup the '[Postfix on hosts without a real Internet hostname](http://www.postfix.org/STANDARD_CONFIGURATION_README.html#fantasy)'. Here is the breakdown on how I completed that step on my Ubuntu box:

```
sudo vim /etc/postfix/main.cf
smtp_generic_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/generic (add this line somewhere)
(edit or create the file 'generic' if it doesn't exist)
sudo vim /etc/postfix/generic
(add these lines, I don't think it matters what names you use, at least to test)
his@localdomain.local             hisaccount@hisisp.example
her@localdomain.local             heraccount@herisp.example
@localdomain.local                hisaccount+local@hisisp.example
then run:
postmap /etc/postfix/generic (this needs to be run whenever you change the 
generic file)
```

Happy Trails

Comment: You have to specify emails in angle brackets, in other case it won't work `MAIL FROM: <somebody@blah.com>`